How to migrate from Git LFS with missing files replacement?
I have a Git repository with LFS. Initially, I committed up to commit A, then deleted the repo. Later, I downloaded it from GitHub and continued committing up to commit B. Now, I don't have access to the original repo and want to migrate from LFS to a regular repo locally and push that as new.
The issue is that I don't have the LFS data for commits before A, and running git lfs migrate export --everything results in an error due to this missing data. I believe it might be possible to use a shell script with git filter-branch to migrate from LFS, replacing the missing files with their versions from later commits, or removing them if they can't be found. Any advice on how to accomplish this?
